The convex hull of extreme points
Let $C$ be a convex set in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $E$ be the set of extreme points of $C$. Suppose that $C$ is the convex hull of $E$ and $\overline{C}$ is compact. I wonder if $C=\overline{C}$ ?
I know that if $C$ is a compact convex set in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $C$ is the convex hull of $E$. But I have no idea on my question.

Should the third sentence instead start as "Suppose that $\overline{C}$ is the convex hull of $E$"?

If you take $C=\{x^2+y^2\le 1\}\cap\{y>0\}$, its extreme points are the half circle contained in $\{y>0\}$ and each point of $C$ can be written as a convex combination of its extreme points (take the horizontal segment). But the set is not closed.
